# Moodle Integration in an ASP.Net site

Tags: c#, asp.net, moodle

In my Asp.net website am trying to integrate Moodle LMS and am done with it.
The problem is like, when i click on logout i need the browser to be redirected to my 
own website's home page. But it is redirecting to 'Index.php' page in Moodle.

Kindly suggest any solution

Comment: Hi, will you give me full process of integration of moodle with asp.net

Comment: Hi praveen could you. please tell me how  to integrate moodle with asp.net mvc4 or mvc5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit "moodledir/login/logout.php" and change the following

$redirect = $CFG->wwwroot.'/';

to...

$redirect = $CFG->logouturl;

Then, in your config.php set a value for $CFG->logouturl e.g.

$logouturl = $CFG->logouturl = 'http://customi.url';

Hope this helps